# Do I have to declare all the original properties from a div in @media query?

Tags: css

Simple question, if I have the following div:

```
.example {
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
display: cover;
margin: auto;
padding-left: 10px
}
```

Do I need to declare all of these properties again in the media query?  Or does it just inherit everything else that I have not changed?  For example, if I just change the height:

```
@media (min-width:1200px) {
    .example {height:100px;}
}
```

Do I then also need to include all of the other properties in my original .example div or is it inherited?  The reason I ask is because I'm trying to troubleshoot some problems with my css and I'm starting to suspect that even if I just want to change one property value in a @media div, I need to include all of the original properties as well or the will default.

Comment: Did you write the @media styles below the original? Then it should just inherit..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need to duplicate all the other properties in a media query, only include the property that the media query is altering. CSS is named *cascading* style sheets because the values cascade down. Media queries follow the standard css cascading.